# PHP: form for editing files

Tags: php, forms, edit

I have created a little file manager with PHP. 
All is working fine, the reading, deleting, moving, editing.
But in the showing of the content of the file to modify, there is a problem.

In a previous form I leave to the user to choose what file to modify, in another page I get the file name, and show in a textarea its content with this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $file = $_POST['file'];
?>

<form action="edit_file_process3.php" method="get">
    <p>This is the content of the file <?php echo $file; ?>. Now you can modify it:</p>
<textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="content"><?php readfile($file)   ?></textarea>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="edit <?php echo $file; ?>" /> </p>
</form>

<a href="read2.php">Come back to the file manager</a>
```

The first time I select a file, in the textarea instead of its proper content, it appears like this:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning xe-scream' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for</th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: readfile(prova4.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\LEARNING\Files\edit_file_process3.php on line <i>50</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>144848</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\LEARNING\Files\edit_file_process3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\edit_file_process3.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>145248</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/readfile' target='_new'>readfile</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\LEARNING\Files\edit_file_process3.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\edit_file_process3.php<b>:</b>50</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

If I overwrite this text with something else then it works, and the next time, the textarea will show the proper content for the file.
But is quite nasty that the first time it does this.
Why does this happen?

Comment: You should use file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() functions instead of readfile() 
Because readfile() reads a file and writes it to the output buffer directly, like echo('file contents') does.

Comment: The error states that the path to the file `prova4.txt` you're trying to read is incorrect.

Comment: I have tried.
With file_get_contents()
and with echo file_get_contents()

But i got the same error

Comment: @budwiser But if i modify that text with something else, than it appear the proper content. If it does it means that (at least after the first time) the file is read properly

Comment: @johnnyfittizio, what do you mean by "modify that text with something else?"

Comment: That if i select all what is inside the textarea and replace it with "Hello". Then as new content of the file will appear "Hello".
And the next times i try to edit that file, in the textarea will appear "Hello", as it should be.

Comment: Does your page allow the user to create a new file? If he's creating a new file, you'll get an error trying to read it before it's created.

Comment: No right now there is no creating option. I will try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the script is looking for the file in the correct directory.

You can use either absolute paths eg. `/from/root/to/my/dir` or relative paths eg. `../where/is/my/file`.

If you are using relative paths, you must have the correct path **relative to the script looking for the file**. Otherwise you'll get nagged *failed to open stream: No such file or directory* as in this case.

**EDIT**

If I understood correctly, you're trying to edit a file that should already exist in your file system. When you try to open it for the first time, you get this error you're describing. That's because the script is looking for the file in the wrong directory. When you "edit it" and save it, just like Barmar pointed out, you're most likely actually creating a new file into another directory. After this, you might have two different files existing in different directories with the same name. Other one is the one that shows up in your "file explorer" and the other being the one you actually edit.

Comment: Thanks! You clarify to me the situation!
I see that three previous files are saved into the root folder with the content modify. The fourth file (the one i would like to edit now) is not there, and is because i have not edit it yet.

So i will try to fix the path.

Comment: Thanks i fix it now. You were right, the file wasn't actually edited as i thought, but rather created anew and saved in the root folder.

And in the 'upload' folder it remained the file with the content without modifications.

So i modify this line in the textarea, in order to read the file properly:

<textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="content"><?php echo file_get_contents("upload/" . $file)   ?></textarea>

And this line in the php script that edit the file:

 $to_modify = fopen("upload/". $filename, "w+") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");

Now it works everything fine!

Comment: I'm very glad I could help. Happy Coding! :D